# How to find In-App Purchases status after user manually cancel auto-renewable subscription in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I purchase a product from iTunes and after sometime i cancelled purchases through iTunes but the subscription period is not finished yet and now i need a mechanism by which i can find the cancellation status for in-app purchases to handle it..

Thanks with regards